# IOS 8 have crash on orientation change

Tags: crash, ios8, orientation

IOS 8 have crash on orientation change....

first we are showing a report as like here..

```
  -(void)didShowReport:(NSString *)fileName andFlag:(BOOL) isWeightReport
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard  storyboardWithName:@"Document_Picker" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"reportNav"];
    NSLog(@"topviewcontrolle - %@",[nav topViewController]);
    SSReportPreviewViewController *reportPreview = (SSReportPreviewViewController *) [nav topViewController];
    reportPreview.fileName = fileName;
    //reportPreview.delegate = self;
    reportPreview.title = [fileName lastPathComponent];
    if(isWeightReport)
        reportPreview.mailSubject = NSLocalizedString(@"weightsummaryreport", @"");
    else
        reportPreview.mailSubject = NSLocalizedString(@"pricesummaryreport", @"");


     [nav setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

after this we are cancelling that view controller using

```
 - (IBAction)onCancel:(id)sender {    
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

after canceling we rotating....crash happening....

error showing.....as like below

```
*** -[UINavigationController _viewControllerForSupportedInterfaceOrientationsWithDismissCheck:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x16ad08c0
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you presenting this after the user presses a button in an action sheet? (Or maybe an alert view?)

iOS 8 now shows action sheets in their own window. (Check which window is key from the app delegate.) If you present a modal before that window is dismissed, the modal will be presented from the action sheet's window (or at least be referenced from it and brought up during rotations.)

Try using didDismissWithButtonIndex: instead of willDismissWithButtonIndex: . 
If that doesn't work, try dispatching your presentation with a 0.1 or 0.2 second delay.  (Sometimes just dispatching to the main queue to give a single run loop delay is enough.)

Comment: we are calling it on a table view did select index method....from there we calling a delegate method ,so that delegate is firing and inside that delegate method this calling  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *file = [self.delegate didSelectedWithReportType:cell.textLabel.text];
    [self.delegate didShowReport:file withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MaintenanceReport", @"")];
    
    }

Comment: this is working perfectly on IOS 7, but in IOS 8 only this problem......inside a table view didselect method we are calling a delegate               [self.delegate didShowReport:file withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MaintenanceReport", @"")];    inside this didshowreport method this view controller is presenting....

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I was using `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` to present a `UINavigationController` as modal, which made the orientation change event crash my app. I changed it to `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` as suggested in this answer.